# Retrieving user name properties for a file

Tags: python

I am able to use the following code to get the size and last modified date.  How can I get the user the file was last modified by?

```
file = "myFileName.xlsx"
size = str(os.path.getsize(file))
lastModified = str(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your (unknown) OS preserve that information for each file?

Comment: I am actually accessing the file on SharePoint.  The SharePoint site does indicate who last modified the file.  I believe it is similar to a Windows file system (WebDAV?)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution, but you can get the user's name by prompting the user to enter a password(if you password protect the file). The getpass() function in the getpass module will prompt the user to enter a password when they try modifying the file. At this point, the getuser() function will fetch the user's name from `os.environ.get('USERNAME')`.

```
import time
import getpass
file = "test.txt"
if file:
    getpass.getpass()
    user = getpass.getuser()
    size = str(os.path.getsize(file))
    lastModified = str(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
    print(size, lastModified, user) #316139 Thu Mar 15 02:11:33 2018 user_name
```

Depending upon your OS configuration and whether the files are stored locally or on the network (such as shared Active Directory sites), the solution will be different. In this case, your question should be more elaborate.